# converting to hexadecimal form using valueOf() method

Tags: java

I have a variable type int, and I have to assign the negative number: -2147483648, the problem is that I am trying to convert it to hexadecimal form using the valueOf() method, and when I try this:

`Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(n),16);` n is the negative number

it throws me the exception java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string :  -214748....

Why am i getting this??

Comment: Because the literal -2147483648 is a decimal number, and you're trying to parse it as if it is in hexadecimal.

Comment: @Jesper And if read as hex, it is beyond the integer range

Answer (score 3):

Use `Integer.toString(n, 16)` instead to get an hexadecimal representation of `n`.

Answer (score 2):

Short explanation of the issue. The problem is that using

```
Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(n),16);
```

you assume that `-2147483648` is an integer in hexadecimal form (you're parsing `-2147483648` with the base of 16) and it's much lesser than `Interger.MIN_VALUE`, so it causes exception. As @Jean suggested, use [`Integer.toString(int i, radix)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString(int,%20int)) instead.

From documentation:

> An exception of type NumberFormatException is thrown if any of the following situations occurs:
>
> - ...
> - The value represented by the string is not a value of type int.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `Integer.valueOf(String, int)` parses your String argument as if it were a base 16 integer. The problem is that exactly one of these 2 constraints does not hold:

- the String argument (base 16) > Integer.MAX_VALUE (base 2), or
- the String argument (base 16) < Integer.MIN_VALUE (base 2)

Checking these constraints is exactly what `Integer.parseInt(String, int)` does for you. If you inspect the source code of `Integer.parseInt(String, int)`, then you'll notice that the exception is thrown from this piece of code:

```
if (result < multmin) {
    throw NumberFormatException.forInputString(s);
}
```

where `result` is the intermediate result while parsing is in progress from the beginning of the String towards the end, and `multmin` is either `Integer.MAX_VALUE / radix` or `-Integer.MAX_VALUE / radix`. (The reason for only adding negatively is that `abs(Integer.MIN_VALUE)` > `abs(Integer.MAX_VALUE)`).

The parsing is in progress and detects that, if there is at least one more additional character to process, one of these constraints must be violated. That is where the exception will be thrown: it indicates that you have fed a parameter to this method that cannot be accepted.